# Merging similar XML structure within one file using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, informatica-cloud

I have the following structure in a XML file where i want to merge all the child nodes provided they have same parent node. I want to remove the duplicates as well. I have provided the example of input XML and required output as well. In the below example, I want to merge all the address related attributes and identifiers since the CUST_NM filed is same for both nodes.

```
<root>
<Objects>
    <CUST_NUM>
        MC0000289917
    </CUST_NUM>
    <FIRST_Nm>
        RONALD
    </FIRST_Nm>
    <Address>   
        <Addr_line_1>
            5655 HUDSON DR
        </Addr_line_1>   
        <Addr_line_2>
            STE 130
        </Addr_line_2>   
    </Address>
    <Identifier>
        <ID_TYP_CD>
            SLN
        </ID_TYP_CD>
        <ID_VAL>
            35
        </ID_VAL>
    </Identifier>
</Objects>
<Objects>
    <CUST_NUM>
        MC0000289917
    </CUST_NUM>
    <FIRST_Nm>
        RONALD
    </FIRST_Nm>
    <Address>   
        <Addr_line_1>
            568 HUDSON DR1
        </Addr_line_1>   
        <Addr_line_2>
            STE 132
        </Addr_line_2>   
    </Address>
    <Identifier>
        <ID_TYP_CD>
           SLN
    </ID_TYP_CD>
    <ID_VAL>
        35
    </ID_VAL>
</Identifier>
```

Desired Output:

```
<root>
<Objects>
    <CUST_NUM>
        MC0000289917
    </CUST_NUM>
    <FIRST_Nm>
        RONALD
    </FIRST_Nm>
    <Address>   
        <Addr_line_1>
            5655 HUDSON DR
            568 HUDSON DR1
        </Addr_line_1>   
        <Addr_line_2>
            STE 130
            STE 132
        </Addr_line_2>   
    </Address>
    <Identifier>
        <ID_TYP_CD>
            SLN
        </ID_TYP_CD>
        <ID_VAL>
            35
        </ID_VAL>
    </Identifier>
</Objects>
```

Comment: What is your context and XQuery engine?

Comment: I want to group all the child nodes if they have same parent node as shown in the above example. I am trying to do it in Informatica on cloud which provides a feature to write XQuery. It supports all XQuery 1.0 constructs and few XQuery 3.0 constructs such as 1- Try - Catch 2 - Group by

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a task to use `group by` repeatedly:

```
/* ! element { node-name() } {
    for $obj in Objects
    group by $cust-no := $obj/CUST_NUM
    return
        <OBJECTS>
        {
            for $child at $pos in $obj/*
            group by $name := node-name($child)
            order by head($pos)
            return 
                element { $name } { 
                    if ($child/*)
                    then for $grand-child at $gpos in $child/*
                         group by $gc-name := node-name($grand-child)
                         order by head($gpos)
                         return 
                             element { $gc-name } { distinct-values($grand-child ! normalize-space(data())) }
                    else distinct-values($child/data()) 
                }
        }
        </OBJECTS>
}
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsC